# Anonymous union emebed into struct which Equivalent to C in Vlang

Tags: vlang

Suppose I have a C code where Anonymous union emebed into struct :

```
  struct sname{
    union{int a;};
    int b;
  }
```

how to write Equivalent code in Vlang ?

I have tried this piece,but it can not pass compilation of V,error happened:`error: unexpected keyword union, expecting name`:

```
struct Sname {
  union {
    a int
   }
   b int
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean [Sum Types](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#sum-types)? The `struct Node` example uses it inside a `struct`.